# CSS: div is placed over ul

Tags: css

I have a CSS problem which I cannot seem to grasp. 
There is a div with `id = "header"`. Under that there is an UL which is my dropdown menu. And under that I have a div with some links.

The problem now is that the last div is not displayed, because it is placed under the UL. I found out that I could fix this with a `margin-top:29px`, as the menubar has that height, but this is not the nicest solution. I want it to be nice and future proof.

I added 2 images where this is visible in Firebug. As you can see in the second picture, the last div is smaller than the menubar and is placed under the menubar.

Hopefully someone can tell me what I am missing.

[image: css image from firebug1]
[image: css image from firebug2]

**EDIT**
I have made a jsfiddle to show what I got now (I am sorry for the CSS that contains lots of lines for the menu)
http://jsfiddle.net/Ecz4W/

Original HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<h1 id="logo"><a href="/">Koffers4u</a></h1>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
<li><a href="./" class="dir">Menu1</a>  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./">All</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="./" class="dir">Menu2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./">All</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div>
<p>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><br/> 
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">cnn.com</a><br/> 
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your css for relevant elements? (Or even better a fiddle) Also are you using display:none or display:hidden for the drop-down menu?

Comment: Could you add your HTML and CSS in *text*, not as *pictures of text*? And, ideally, post a [live demo for us to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I have added the jsfiddle with the example.

Comment: *There is a div with id = "header"*". In this wonderful era of HTML5 semantic markup, please use `<header>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the `position:absolute` off you `ul.dropdown` it should work properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ecz4W/1/

Answer (score 0):

use the z-index to place your elements in a certain order on the stack. More info:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/